# How does "Living review" style of publishing work

Tags: publications, research-process, journals

There are journals like "Living reviews in Special Relativity' etc.... They claim that they keep the information up to date, but how does this kind of publishing process work?

Answer (score 5):

The [Living Reviews](http://www.springer.com/gb/livingreviews) that I know

1. solicit articles from authors, rather than accept submissions
2. ask the authors to revisit and revise the articles to keep them up to date.
3. are online review articles only.

Other than that, they are "standard" journals and peer reviewed.

The revision history of articles can be seen explicitly on each article, as [this example](https://link.springer.com/article/10.12942/lrr-2003-7#article-history) shows.

Whilst many reviews are written, few are revised to keep them up to date, and even fewer are revised more than once. From what I've heard the process is: editor hassles author to bring article up to date, author replies that not much has changed or that they don't have enough time right now, wait a year and repeat.